# boost::multi_index multiple keys from the same object

Tags: c++, boost

Let's say I have an object, that can be identified by different names from different namespaces:

```
enum Namespace {
    nspaceA,
    nspaceB
};

struct Object {
    int id;
    std::map<Namespace, std::string> names;
};
```

Now I want to store instances of `Object` in `boost::multi_index` and being able to find an object by unique id as well as namespace/symbol pair:

```
array.find( boost::make_tuple( nspaceA, "foobar" ) );
```

So candidate would be a composite key, and as much as I understand, one object can represent only one key. But one `Object` instance has names in different namespaces. Is there a way to solve this with `boost::multi_index` array?

Comment: Can their be collision between the names across the namesapce?  So can "foobar" on `nspaceA` refer to a different object than "foobar" on `nspaceB`?  If _not_, then you can do this with `boost::multi_index`, but if so...

Comment: Probably not, but I cannot guarantee that and would prefer to maintain separate container rather than count on this.

Comment: @Chad The same object may have the same name in different namespaces for sure, so I guess that breaks it anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple objects in the container, where each object references the original object you want to store.

So for instance if you have an object of type Foo that can be referenced by several different keys, where each key is a namespace + name pair, then you can for instance store objects of type

```
struct Key {
  Namespace namespace;
  std::string name;
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> object;
};
```

instead of storing Foo objects directly.

Update (after the question was updated):
If you need to look up the objects in other ways such as by id, then you will either need to make the index non-unique or store the objects in a secondary container.

Another option could be to separate the namespaces into different indexes on the container, which of course doesn't work in all scenarios either.

Comment: This is obvious, store multiple pointers to the same object, but then I cannot use other keys, like unique id, let me modify the question

Comment: No, that is true, but you can store the objects themselves elsewhere.

Comment: Then I need to keep 2 containers in sync manually, which I want to avoid and that's why I try to use `boost::multi_index`. So this is not a solution I am afraid

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but it seems to me that if you use a non-unique index for the id field, you will not need to keep things in sync manually?

Comment: non-unique index breaks data validation on the one side, and I have to manually add multiple indexes on insertion on another. Only benefit it gives me - data removal in one shot. I am afraid loosing ability to have unique index is too much price for gain. But let's count it as a partial solution.

Comment: I agree, unless you need the multiindex for something else as well, such as looking up objects by something else. Or if you can live with having separate indexes per namespace for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `Namespace`has only two values, wouldn't you be better off defining `Object` like this?

```
struct Object {
    int id;
    std::string nameA,nameB; // potentially empty
};
```

In this case, `Objects`can be easily indexed by `id`, `nameA` and `nameB`.

Comment: This is not real code but minimal example. It is strange that you deduce requirements from it.

Comment: Put another way, if the number *N* of different keys in the `names` map is small (say <5) it might be better to expand it to *N* data members.

Comment: And use a switch to find object by namespace/name combination? Btw to create N indexes I do not have to convert `map` into data members.

Comment: Not a `switch`, but a linear scan of all the indices. Yes, you don't need to drop your `map` to do this.

Comment: As I said in the question, I need to find an object by namespace/name combination (there is an example). How would I do that without switch and with linear scan?

Comment: You try finding on the first index, then on the second etc. till you are finished or have success in the process.